# (Android) Navigation drawer with Multi-pane layouts

Tags: android, layout, tablet, navigation-drawer

I have a hard time trying to come with a good and acceptable layout for an activity for **a tablet**, but I'm not sure that if my design is compatible with Google's design guidelines.

In short: my application receives a network sniffer log file and shows statistics on different features on the data. For example, traffic over time, PM over time, show the traffic as a time line, different graphs, pie charts etc.

The first thing comes to mind for a design for this activity is a multi-pane layout (like Gmail's for tablets). The first pane would be the different features specified above, the second would have controls on the third one (which would display a graph) to filter different data, colorize and other things and settings.

**The problem is,** the second pane is not a list that opens a content (like in Gmail), but a pane that controls the third one.

My solution for this is to create just a two-pane layout: Only the second one (with the controls) and of course the third one with the graphs. The list of the features would be on a navigation drawer that the user would have to slide in order to switch to another feature.

Is this design compatible with Google's design guidelines? Is it logical for the user?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't recommend using the navigation drawer for tablets, at least not in **landscape** mode. Three panels should work fine and you can use the navigation drawer for **portrait** mode only.

Android design methodology is flexible so instead of trying to use the latest design patterns try figuring out what best suits your data.

Anyway, a good example for an app displaying content in 3 different panels is the Android Wordpress app. Check it out here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.wordpress.android

Comment: Could you explain why you not reommend using navigation drawers for tablets? I'm developing an android aplication and I want to use a hidden menu (navigation drawer) for portrait and a visible menu for landscape.

Comment: That's what I was saying. To use navigation drawer in portrait and an always visible navigation pane for landscape mode. This is the way I do it as well. The answer above was tailored for the question, I did not refer to 'any' Android application on tablets.