# How to provide navigation for an app that supports tablets and handsets

Tags: android-fragments, navigation-drawer, android, landscape-portrait

I know this might been asked before but since I didn't find anything convincing, I need to ask again.

**How do you design an app that's going to support tablets and handsets when you also need to provide some sort navigation panel(e.g. [Navigation Drawer](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html))?**

I think I know how to use the Navigation Drawer with handsets and tablets in portrait orientation because in those cases I'm only showing a single pane(fragment) at the time. But with tablets in landscape that's totally different since you have enough room to display at least two panes(fragments) that most of the time are going to be related in a sort of "mater-detail" way.

## Edit #1

---

Just to provide a bit of context about my app and why I think I need to have two panes apart from the navigation list.

Well the main goal of my app is to help waiters **take orders**, this scenario comes into play when:

1. The waiter selects the option "Take order" from the left menu (ideally a navigation drawer)
2. In the first part(left pane)  of the the what I called the "Content Part", the waiter can choose among all the categories of food they serve (pretend it's the list at the top) and according to the category selected, the below list shows all the dishes under that specific category.
3. Once the waiter taps on a dish it's automatically added to the second part(right pane)  of the "Content Part"

[image]

---

Knowing that the basic structure of a navigation drawer is similar to this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <!-- The main content view -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/content_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How do you handle the "tablet-in-landscape-orientation" scenario? Do you use nested fragments for the multi-pane layout that might be necessary to use in this case?(that sounds awfully complicated) Do you use a custom library perhaps? Do you know of any open source app in Git that implements this and that I can use as a reference?

## EDIT #2

After trying some ideas, I realized that the most convenient way of implementing the same navigation drawer for multiple activities, was to create a `BaseActivity` that would handle all the drawer functionality and from which all my activities could inherit.

This is what I've got so far:

**BaseActivity**

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class BaseActivity extends Activity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private ListView mDrawerListView;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState, int resLayoutID) {

        setContentView(resLayoutID);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setupNavDrawer();
    }

    private void setupNavDrawer() {
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        mDrawerListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

        String[] rows = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_rows);
        mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, R.layout.drawer_row, rows));
        mDrawerToggle =
                new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                        R.string.drawer_open,
                        R.string.drawer_close);

        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View row,
                                    int position, long id) {
                if (position == 0) {
                    Log.d("Menu", "European Union");
                } else {
                    Log.d("Menu", "Other Option");
                }
                mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
            }

        });
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }


    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Every activity that needs to have a Navigation Drawer now needs to extend the `BaseActivity`:

**EuropeanUnionActivity**

```
public class EuropeanUnionActivity extends BaseActivity{
    //...
}
```

Also every activity layout needs to contain in its code a `android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout` element like this:

**activity_europeanunion**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include layout="@layout/main" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Here's important to mention that the ID's for the `DrawerLayout`(drawer_layout) and the `ListView`(drawer) needs to be the same in all the activity layouts that are going to have a navigation drawer because those ID's are used by the `BaseActivity`.

For the sake of brevity and to quickly test this approach I have used [this example](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/LargeScreen/EU4You) by @CommonsWare (I hope he doesn't mind). There you can find the implementation for `@layout/main`.

Now, although almost everything works as expected, I haven't been able to understand why if I take the code for the `ListView` and place it in a separate file **listview_options** the Navigation drawer simply wouldn't close and tapping on the `ActionBarDrawerToggle` would only make the app crash and show this in the LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.idealsolution.simplenavigationdrawer, PID: 17725
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
            at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1293)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.toggle(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:290)
            at android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:280)
            at com.idealsolution.simplenavigationdrawer.BaseActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(BaseActivity.java:86)
            at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:2608)
            at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarView$3.onClick(ActionBarView.java:167)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4456)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18465)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**This is line 86:**

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) { //Line 86
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

This is the same code for 
**activity_europeanunion**, but using a `include` tag for the `ListView`

```
<include layout="@layout/main" />
<include layout="@layout/listview_options" />
```

The code for **listview_options.xml** :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/menu_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:background="#111"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

This is the code I tried in the `BaseActivity` to retrieve the `ListView`, but that obviously isn't working:

```
    private void setupNavDrawer() {
            mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


           //Please pay special attention to the following two lines
            mDrawerLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.menu_layout);
            mDrawerListView = (ListView) mDrawerLinearLayout.findViewById(R.id.drawer);


            mDrawerListView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);

            String[] rows = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawer_rows);
            mDrawerListView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                    this, R.layout.drawer_row, rows));
            mDrawerToggle =
                    new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                            R.string.drawer_open,
                            R.string.drawer_close);
            mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
            mDrawerListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View row,
                                        int position, long id) {
                    //...
                    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
                }

            });
            getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
```

Any ideas and suggestions are welcome.
Thanks.

P.S. I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19368595/android-navigation-drawer-with-multi-pane-layouts) in which it is said that using a Navigation Drawer is not advisable.

Comment: The three panel suggested in that question is a good fit for that scenario, but you could show only two panels: one with the navigation list and the other the current fragment. It would work as if the drawer was always open

Comment: "How do you handle the "tablet-in-landscape-orientation" scenario? " -- um, replace the `FrameLayout` with a horizontal `LinearLayout` to hold your two panes? I fail to see how a nav drawer impacts matters. You would implement the master/detail the same way you would *without* a nav drawer. You could even put the `LinearLayout` in a separate XML file and use `<include>` to put it in the overall layout with the `DrawerLayout`, if it helped you visualize matters.

Comment: @JavierMollá Yes two panes would be just fine if I didn't have to use two panes ,without taking into account the navigation list. You see I've got this scenario in which I think I've got no choice, but to use two panes when my app is displayed in a landscape orientation. [In this question](http://goo.gl/E37NSu) in the #Edit part (3rd scenario) I describe why I need two panes.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare I really like you idea of using a horizontal `LinearLayout`(with two `FrameLayouts` I guess) instead of using directly a single `FrameLayout`, the problem is that I don't know how to deal the `Activity`, or whatever that handles the `LinearLayout`. I'm just starting to use Fragments and I'm using your book (borrowed from Uni) to learn about it and I wanted to use your "List-and-Detail Pattern", but to be honest I don't know how to make the `DrawerLayout` fit into that pattern and I really need some sort of navigation in my app.The more reusable, the better.

Comment: @CommonsWare I edited my question with more details and an image to show why I think I have to use two panes apart from the navigation list. Please, take a look at it.

Comment: "The waiter selects the option "Take order" from the left menu (ideally a navigation drawer)" -- entries in a navigation drawer should be nouns, not verbs/commands, according to Google's design guidelines. "I think I have to use two panes apart from the navigation list" -- yes, but those panes can be contained in a horizontal `LinearLayout`. `DrawerLayout` is what constrains you to having a "single" thing in the UI beyond the drawer, but it says nothing about what is inside that "single" thing. If you want two `FrameLayout`s in there, go for it.

Comment: @CommonsWare but how could I handle that "single" thing is the question? I've trying to find something similar, but I haven't been able to find anything and something that I was forgetting is that the `LinearLayout` is not always going to show two panes, as that is going to be determined by the option selected on `DrawerLayout`.

Comment: You can always make one of the panes go away via `setVisibilitity(View.GONE)` when you do not need it. If you are using weights properly, the other pane will then expand to fill all the available space.

Comment: @CommonsWare So in the end using a `DrawerLayout` for handsets and tablets (in any orientation) would it be completely viable? Would you use that approach? Or would you try something completely different? I'm really interested in knowing how a professional would address an app.like the one described in my question and based on that, I can go and do so researching.

Comment: "So in the end using a DrawerLayout for handsets and tablets (in any orientation) would it be completely viable?" -- sure. "Would you use that approach?" -- not for your described usage, as I would stick to using the drawer more in lines with Google's design guidelines (nouns, not verbs). But, beyond that, sure.

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare . Just one last question, what do you think of what suggested :  "If navigation drawer is visible on all activities, I have an abstract activity where I take care of the drawer. Then, all the activities inherit from this abstract activity" ? Will it make things easier?

Comment: I suspect that a lot of navigation drawer apps go with the "single activity" model, where everything is just fragments coming and going, rather than transitioning between activities. That being said, I don't see a particular problem with your approach, if it works to your satisfaction.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare, sorry to bother you, but I've got a similar situation and I don't know what to do. In you first comment you say _"replace the FrameLayout with a horizontal LinearLayout to hold your two panes? I fail to see how a nav drawer impacts matters. You would implement the master/detail the same way you would without a nav drawer. You could even put the LinearLayout in a separate XML file and use <include>"_ I want to do that, but I  don't understand how can I then display another activity inside the same `LinearLayout`. With fragments is just by using `replace`, but with activities?

Comment: @Axel: "I don't understand how can I then display another activity inside the same LinearLayout" -- you don't. The master detail pattern, on tablets, is classically implemented using fragments. At most, you transition to another activity for another major functional or content area.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare. I've updated my question with what I've achieved so far. Do you think you could take a look at the **Edit #2**. I decided to implement a `BaseActivity` that handles all the Drawer logic. The only problem now is that if I want to put the `ListView` that represents the drawer options in a separate file and then call it using <include> the drawer wouldn't close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For phone and tablet-portrait mode you can use a layout like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/fragments_layout" />
    <include layout="@layout/drawer_list" />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

This could be the layout for the tablet-landscape mode:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <include layout="@layout/drawer_list" />
    <include layout="@layout/fragments_layout" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is drawer_list:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="260dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:background="#111"
        android:divider="@android:color/darker_gray"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and fragments_layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment android:id="+@id/master_fragment" />
    <fragment android:id="+@id/detail_fragment" />
</FrameLayout>
```

On the activity, you'll have to check if you're in tablet-landscape mode and show both fragments. Otherwise, you'll show master fragment first, hiding the details

If navigation drawer is visible on all activities, declare an abstract activity that takes care of the drawer. Then, all the activities inherit from this abstract activity. The BaseActivity you posted is a good example

Comment: Let me see I understand you.The layout for phone and tablet-portrait mode can go inside a `res\layout\main.xml` and be the default layout, while the layout for tablet-landscape mode can go inside `res\layout-w720dp\main.xml`, but then what? The java code is that part that really confuses me. Is the Activity that inflates either of the main.xml versions the same responsible for loading the overall layout, the one indicating which fragments should be loaded and populating those “slots” with the appropriate fragments and also handling any events that are triggered by UI work in a fragment?

Comment: The system is responsible for loading layout\main.xml or \layout-w720dp\main.xml but you'll be responsible (on the code) of showing both fragments (tablet-landscape) or only one at a time (phone)

Comment: and also the option selected in the `drawer_list`? If that is so, that sounds like a lot of work for a single Activity, but as mentioned in my question, I'm really new to fragments and I might be making a mountain out of a molehill

Comment: If navigation drawer is visible on all activities, I have an abstract activity where I take care of the drawer. Then, all the activities inherit from this abstract activity

Comment: Yes, I think I need the drawer on all my activities.

Comment: Hi Javier, I decided to go with `BaseActivity` approach that you suggested, but I've encountered a problem when I tried to put the `ListView` in a separate file so that I can reuse it later. Please take a look at the **Edit #2** of my question.

Comment: Post listview_options.xml

Comment: Sorry about that @Javier. I've already posted the code for **listview_options.xml**

Comment: I can't see where is the problem. Post the stacktrace, too, please

Comment: I'll post the stacktrace a bit later because I'm not at home at the moment, and I don't have my laptop with me. The strange thing is that when I put the `ListView` directly in the file **listview_options.xml** without nesting it inside a `LinearLayout` it worked correctly.

Comment: Put android:layout_width="240dp" on LinearLayout and android:layout_width="match_parent on ListView"

Comment: Hi Javier. I tried what you suggested in your previous comment, but the only difference was that this time the drawer would take up the whole screen and when I try to use the mDrawerToggle the app would crash with the exact same error that I was getting. In any case, I've just added the stacktrace to my question.

Comment: Thank you Javier. Now it works correctly, but you forgot this bit of code `android:background="#111"`. Without that property the drawer would always be display as a grey background and would be impossible tell apart the actual background and the drawer itself.Now, knowing that I can put the `ListView` in a separate file either within a Linear/Relative Layout or directly in the file, when do you consider necessary to nest your Views inside a Layout and when to put them directly in the file?

Comment: Umm, logically, if there's only going to be one element inside a layout, you could make that element the root. This should be better for performance and maintainability, also. So direct would be a bit better than nested, I guess

Comment: Got it. Javier please edit your answer with the property that was missing and please mention the thing about using a BaseActivity so that I can mark your answer.

Comment: Thank you very much Javier without your help I'd still be looking for a solution.